# SASS Compile "finished without @return"

Tags: css, sass

As part of a much bigger suite of SCSS code, I have a library mixin for creating a variety of backgrounds.  I've separated them into a single SCSS file, whic contains the mixin and the intended class to use it in at the bottom of the page:

```
// Background handling mixin
// @version: 1.0.0
// @author: Simon Buerger (simon.buerger@heathwallace.com)
// 
// Purpose: Primarily for the creation of gradients (linear, radial, repeating) - outputting all the required vendor prefixed versions of the property from the unprefixed syntax. Complete with error correction for the quirks of the 3 different syntaxes
// Supports: multiple backgrounds, any number of arguments per background (for gradients you must use the unprefixed syntax)
// Output: either background-image or background (automatically decides which is appropriate)
//
// Usage: @include background([Anything that either background or background-image accept as values - unprefixed]);
//    Eg: @include background(
//              linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, green 20%, black),
//              radial-gradient(farthest-side circle at 100% 30%, black, blue 10%, white),
//              url(/assets/main-site/images/test.png),
//              url(/assets/main-site/images/test2.png) no-repeat left center
//        );

$parsegradients:true;
$gradientvendors: (webkitlegacy,webkit,moz,o);
$usevendors: null;


@mixin background($args...) {
    $usevendors: $gradientvendors !default;
    $backgrounds: false;
    $current-vendor: false;
    $vendored: false;
    $gradvendors: append($usevendors, none, comma);
    @debug "===============  Background mixin ===================";

    @each $vendor in $gradvendors {
        $backgrounds: false;
        $current-vendor: $vendor;
        $bgprops:false;
        $propsdef:false;
        @each $arg in $args {
            @if nth($arg,1) == linear-grad or nth($arg,1) == rep-linear-grad or nth($arg,1) == radial-grad or nth($arg,1) == rep-radial-grad{
                $parsedbg:false;
                $vendored:true;
                @if nth($arg,1) == linear-grad or nth($arg,1) == rep-linear-grad {
                    @debug "calling linear";
                    $parsedbg:parselinear($arg);
                    @debug "Got linear output: " + $parsedbg;
                }
                @else {
                    @debug "calling radial";
                    $parsedbg:parseradial($arg);
                    @debug "Got radial output: " + $parsedbg;
                }
                @if $parsedbg {
                    @if $backgrounds {
                        $backgrounds: append($backgrounds,#{$parsedbg},comma);
                    }
                    @else {
                        $backgrounds: #{$parsedbg};
                    }
                    @debug "Length: " + length($backgrounds);
                }
            }
        }

        @if $vendored {
            @if $backgrounds and $propsdef {
                background:#{$backgrounds};         
            }
            @else if $backgrounds {
                background-image:#{$backgrounds};           
            }
        }
        @else if $current-vendor == none {
            @if $backgrounds and $propsdef {
                background:#{$backgrounds};         
            }
            @else if $backgrounds {
                background-image:#{$backgrounds};           
            }
        }
    }
$usevendors: $gradientvendors;
}

$current-vendor: false;

@function parseradial($args...) {
    $bg-vars:false;
    $color-stops:false;
    $shapedef:false;
    $position: false;
    $size: false;
    $shape: false;
    $bg-string:false;
    $repeating: false;
    $mozexplicit:false;
    @each $arg in $args {
        $noshape:false;
        @each $var in $arg {
            @if $var != radial-grad and $var != rep-radial-grad {
                @if $bg-vars {
                    $bg-vars: append($bg-vars,$var,comma);
                }
                @else {
                    @if type-of($var) == list and type-of(nth($var,1)) == color or type-of($var) == list and nth($var,1) == transparent {
                        $bg-vars: #{$var};
                        $noshape:true;
                    }
                    @else {
                        $bg-vars: $var;
                    }
                }
            }
            @if $var == rep-radial-grad {
                $repeating:repeating-;
            }
        }
        @each $bg-var in $bg-vars {
            @if type-of($bg-var) == list and type-of(nth($bg-var,1)) == color or type-of($bg-var) == list and nth($bg-var,1) == transparent or type-of($bg-var) == color or $bg-var == transparent {
                @if $color-stops {
                    $color-stops: append($color-stops,#{$bg-var},comma);
                }
                @else {
                    $color-stops: #{$bg-var};
                }
            }
            @else {
                @if $noshape {
                    $color-stops: #{$bg-var};
                }
                @else if $shapedef {
                    $shapedef: append($shapedef,$bg-var,space);
                }
                @else {
                    $shapedef: #{$bg-var};
                }
            }
        }
        @if $shapedef {
            @if index($shapedef, at) {
                @each $sub-var in $shapedef {
                    @if index($shapedef,$sub-var) > index($shapedef, at) {
                        @if $position {
                            $position: append($position,$sub-var,space);
                        }
                        @else {
                            $position: $sub-var;
                        }
                    }
                    @else if index($shapedef,$sub-var) < index($shapedef, at) {
                        @if $sub-var == circle or $sub-var == ellipsis {
                            $shape: $sub-var;
                        }
                        @else {
                            @if $size {
                                $size: append($size,$sub-var,space)
                            }
                            @else {
                                $size: $sub-var;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @else {
                @each $sub-var in $shapedef {

                    @if $sub-var == circle or $sub-var == ellipsis {
                        $shape: $sub-var;
                    }
                    @else {
                        @if $size {
                            $size: append($size,$sub-var,space)
                        }
                        @else {
                            $size: $sub-var;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @if $position {
            $bg-string:#{$position};
        }
        @if $shape and $size {
            @if $size == closest-side or $size == farthest-side or $size == closest-corner or $size == farthest-corner {
                @if $bg-string {
                    $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$shape} #{$size}, comma);
                }
                @else {
                    $bg-string:#{$shape} #{$size};
                }
            }
            @else if type-of($size) == string {
                $mozexplicit:true;
                @if $bg-string {
                    $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$size} #{$size}, comma);
                }
                @else {
                    $bg-string:#{$size} #{$size};
                }
            }
            @else {
                @if $bg-string {
                    $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$shape} #{$size}, comma);
                }
                @else {
                    $bg-string:#{$shape} #{$size};
                }
            }
        }
        @else {
            @if $size {
                @if $size == closest-side or $size == farthest-side or $size == closest-corner or $size == farthest-corner {
                    @if $bg-string {
                        $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$size}, comma);
                    }
                    @else {
                        $bg-string:#{$size};
                    }
                }
                @else if type-of($size) == string {
                    $mozexplicit:true;
                    @if $bg-string {
                        $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$size} #{$size}, comma);
                    }
                    @else {
                        $bg-string:#{$size} #{$size};
                    }
                }
                @else {
                    @if $bg-string {
                        $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$size}, comma);
                    }
                    @else {
                        $bg-string:#{$size};
                    }
                }
            }
            @if $shape {
                @if $bg-string {
                    $bg-string:append($bg-string, #{$shape}, comma);
                }
                @else {
                    $bg-string:#{$shape};
                }
            }
        }
        @if $bg-string {
            $bg-string: append($bg-string, #{$color-stops}, comma);
        }
        @else {
            $bg-string: #{$color-stops};
        }

        @debug"vendor: " + $current-vendor;
        @if $current-vendor == none {
            @if $shapedef {
                $bg-string:append(#{$shapedef}, #{$color-stops}, comma)
            }
            @else {
                $bg-string:#{$color-stops};
            }
            @return #{if($repeating,$repeating,unquote(''))}#{radial-gradient}unquote('(')#{$bg-string}unquote(')')
        }
        @if $current-vendor == moz and $mozexplicit {
            @warn "prefixed mozilla syntax doesn't support explicitly defined sizes for radial gradients, -moz- syntax excluded";
            @return false
        }
        @if $current-vendor == webkit or $current-vendor == moz or $current-vendor == o {
            @return -#{$current-vendor}-#{if($repeating,$repeating,unquote(''))}#{radial-gradient}unquote('(')#{$bg-string}unquote(')')
        }
        @if $current-vendor == webkitlegacy {
            @warn "no output for webkit-legacy";
            @return false
        }
    }
}

@function parselinear_old($args...) {
    @return "hoskins";
    }

@function parselinear($args...) {
    $bg-vars:false;
    $bg-string:false;
    $started: false;
    $percentagestops: true;
    $repeating: false;
    $startindex: false;
    $startpercent: false;
    $color-join: false;
    $nextpercent: false;
    $nextindex: false;
    @each $arg in $args {
        @debug "Arg:" + $arg;
        @each $var in $arg {
            @if $var != linear-grad and $var != rep-linear-grad {
                @if $bg-vars {
                    $bg-vars: append($bg-vars,$var,comma);
                }
                @else {
                    @if type-of($var) == number or type-of($var) == color or $var == transparent {
                        $bg-vars: $var;
                        @if $current-vendor == webkitlegacy and type-of($var) != number {
                            $bg-vars: append(#{to bottom},$var,comma);
                        }
                    }
                    @else {
                        @if type-of(nth($var,1)) == color or nth($var,1) == transparent {
                            $bg-vars: #{$var};
                            @if $current-vendor == webkitlegacy {
                                $bg-vars: append(#{to bottom},$var,comma);
                            }
                        }
                        @else {
                            $bg-vars: #{$var};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @if $var == rep-linear-grad {
                $repeating:repeating-;
            }
        }
        $stopIndex:1;
        @each $bg-var in $bg-vars {
            @if $current-vendor == webkitlegacy {
                @if $bg-string and $percentagestops {
                    $color-stop:false;
                    $color:false;
                    @if type-of($bg-var) == list {
                        @each $sub-arg in $bg-var {
                            @if type-of($sub-arg) == number {
                                $color-stop: $sub-arg;
                                $startpercent: $sub-arg;
                                @if $started == false {
                                    $started: true;
                                    $startindex:index($bg-vars, $bg-var);
                                    $startpercent: $sub-arg;
                                }
                            }
                            @else {
                                $color:$sub-arg;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @else {
                        @if type-of($bg-var) == color or $bg-var == transparent {
                            $color: $bg-var;
                            @if $started == false {
                                $color-stop:0%;
                                $started: true;
                                $startindex:$stopIndex;
                                $startpercent:$color-stop;
                            }
                            @else if $stopIndex == length($bg-vars) {
                                $color-stop:100%;
                            }
                            @else if $startindex and $startpercent {
                                $i: length($bg-vars);
                                @while $i > $stopIndex {
                                    @if type-of(nth($bg-vars, $i)) == list {
                                        $nextindex: $i;
                                        $nextpercent: nth(nth($bg-vars, $i), 2);
                                    }
                                    @else if $i == length($bg-vars) {
                                        $nextindex: $i;
                                        $nextpercent: 100%;
                                    }
                                    $i: $i - 1;
                                }
                                $j: $startindex;
                                @while $j < $stopIndex {
                                    @if type-of(nth($bg-vars, $j)) == list {
                                        $startindex: $j;
                                        $startpercent: nth(nth($bg-vars, $j), 2);
                                    }
                                    $j: $j + 1;
                                }

                                $color-stop: ($nextpercent - $startpercent)/($nextindex - $startindex) + $startpercent;
                                $startpercent: $color-stop;
                                $startindex:$stopIndex;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @if $color-stop and $color {
                        $color-join: join($color-stop,$color,comma);
                    }
                    @if $color-stop {
                        @if unit($color-stop) != "%" {
                            $percentagestops:false;
                        }
                    }
                    @if $color-join {
                        $bg-string: append($bg-string,#{color-stop}unquote('(')#{$color-join}unquote(')'),comma);
                    }
                }
                @else {
                    @if type-of($bg-var) == number {
                        $angle: $bg-var;
                        $matchedset: false;
                        $small: 360;
                        @if $angle < 0deg {
                            $angle: $angle + 360;
                        }
                        @each $adjustedangle in $legacywebkit-offdeg-matrix {
                            $match: $adjustedangle - $angle;

                            @if $match < 0deg {
                                $match: $angle - $adjustedangle;
                            }
                            @if $matchedset {
                                $matchedset: append($matchedset,$match/1deg,comma);
                            }
                            @else {
                                $matchedset: $match/1deg;
                            }

                        }
                        @each $val in $matchedset {
                            @if $val < $small {
                                $small: $val;
                            }
                        }
                        $closest: index($matchedset,$small);
                        $closestmatch: nth($legacywebkit-offdeg-matrix,$closest);
                        $direction: quote(#{$closestmatch});

                        @each $translation in $legacywebkit-linear-gradient-translation-matrix {
                            @if nth($translation,1) == $direction {
                                $bg-string: unquote(#{nth($translation,2)});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @else if type-of($bg-var) == list and type-of(nth($bg-var,2)) == number and unit(nth($bg-var,2)) != "%" {
                        $percentagestops:false;
                    }
                    @else {
                        $direction: quote(#{$bg-var});
                        @each $translation in $legacywebkit-linear-gradient-translation-matrix {
                            @if nth($translation,1) == $direction {
                                $bg-string: unquote(#{nth($translation,2)});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            @else {
                @if $bg-string {
                    $bg-string: append($bg-string,#{$bg-var},comma);
                }
                @else {
                    @if $current-vendor == none {
                        $bg-string: #{$bg-var};
                    }
                    @else {
                        $direction: quote(#{$bg-var});
                        $bg-string: unquote($direction);
                        @if type-of($bg-var) == number {
                            $bg-string:90 - $bg-var;
                        }
                        @else {
                            @each $translation in $linear-gradient-translation-matrix {
                                @if nth($translation,1) == $direction {
                                    $bg-string: unquote(#{nth($translation,2)});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $stopIndex:$stopIndex + 1;
        }

        @if $current-vendor == none {
            @return #{if($repeating,$repeating,unquote(''))}#{linear-gradient}unquote('(')#{$bg-string}unquote(')')
        }
        @if $current-vendor == webkit or $current-vendor == moz or $current-vendor == o {
            @return -#{$current-vendor}-#{if($repeating,$repeating,unquote(''))}#{linear-gradient}unquote('(')#{$bg-string}unquote(')')
        }
        @if $current-vendor == webkitlegacy and $percentagestops and $repeating == false {
            @return #{-webkit-gradient}unquote('(linear,')#{$bg-string}unquote(')')
        }
        @if $percentagestops == false and $repeating == false {
            @warn "legacy webkit gradient syntax only supports % values for color stops, this gradient will not be included in the output";
            @return false
        }    
        @if $repeating {
            @return false
        }
    }
}


$linear-gradient-translation-matrix: (
    ('to bottom','top')
    ('to top','bottom')
    ('to left','right')
    ('to right','left')
    ('to bottom right','top left')
    ('to right bottom','top left')
    ('to bottom left','top right')
    ('to left bottom','top right')
    ('to top left','bottom right')
    ('to left top','bottom right')
    ('to top right','bottom left')
    ('to right top','bottom left')
);

$legacywebkit-linear-gradient-translation-matrix: (
    ('to bottom',' 0 0, 0 100%')
    ('180deg',' 0 0, 0 100%')
    ('-180deg',' 0 0, 0 100%')
    ('to top',' 0 100%, 0 0')
    ('0deg',' 0 100%, 0 0')
    ('360deg',' 0 100%, 0 0')
    ('to left',' 100% 0, 0 0')
    ('-90deg',' 100% 0, 0 0')
    ('270deg',' 100% 0, 0 0')
    ('to right',' 0 0, 100% 0')
    ('90deg',' 0 0, 100% 0')
    ('-270deg',' 0 0, 100% 0')
    ('to bottom right',' 0 0, 100% 100%')
    ('to right bottom',' 0 0, 100% 100%')
    ('135deg',' 0 0, 100% 100%')
    ('-225deg',' 0 0, 100% 100%')
    ('to bottom left',' 100% 0, 0 100%')
    ('to left bottom',' 100% 0, 0 100%')
    ('-135deg',' 100% 0, 0 100%')
    ('225deg',' 100% 0, 0 100%')
    ('to top left',' 100% 100%, 0 0')
    ('to left top',' 100% 100%, 0 0')
    ('-45deg',' 100% 100%, 0 0')
    ('315deg',' 100% 100%, 0 0')
    ('to top right',' 0 100%, 100% 0')
    ('to right top',' 0 100%, 100% 0')
    ('45deg',' 0 100%, 100% 0')
    ('-315deg',' 0 100%, 100% 0')
);

$legacywebkit-offdeg-matrix: (360deg,315deg,270deg,225deg,180deg,135deg,90deg,45deg,0deg);


@function linear-gradient($args...) {

    @if $parsegradients {
        @if length($args) > 1 {
            $outputs: linear-grad;
            @each $arg in $args {
                @if $outputs {
                    $outputs: append($outputs,$arg, comma);
                }
            }
            @return $outputs
        }
        @else {
            @warn "linear gradients require at least 2 arguments, the expression linear-gradient(#{$args}) was not parsed";
            @return unquote("")
        }
    }
    @else {
        @return #{linear-gradient}unquote('(')#{$args}unquote(')')
    }
}

@function repeating-linear-gradient($args...) {

    @if $parsegradients {
        @if length($args) > 1 {
            $outputs: rep-linear-grad;
            @each $arg in $args {
                @if $outputs {
                    $outputs: append($outputs,$arg, comma);
                }
            }
            @return $outputs
        }
        @else {
            @warn "repeating linear gradients require at least 2 arguments, the expression repeating linear-gradient(#{$args}) was not parsed";
            @return unquote("")
        }
    }
    @else {
        @return #{repeating-linear-gradient}unquote('(')#{$args}unquote(')')
    }
}


@function radial-gradient($args...) {

    @if $parsegradients {
        @if length($args) > 1 {
            $outputs: radial-grad;
            @each $arg in $args {
                @if $outputs {
                    $outputs: append($outputs,$arg, comma);
                }
            }
            @return $outputs
        }
        @else {
            @warn "radial gradients require at least 2 arguments, the expression radial-gradient(#{$args}) was not parsed";
            @return unquote("")
        }
    }
    @else {
        @return #{radial-gradient}unquote('(')#{$args}unquote(')')
    }
}

@function repeating-radial-gradient($args...) {

    @if $parsegradients {
        @if length($args) > 1 {
            $outputs: rep-radial-grad;
            @each $arg in $args {
                @if $outputs {
                    $outputs: append($outputs,$arg, comma);
                }
            }
            @return $outputs
        }
        @else {
            @warn "radial gradients require at least 2 arguments, the expression repeating-radial-gradient(#{$args}) was not parsed";
            @return unquote("")
        }
    }
    @else {
        @return #{radial-gradient}unquote('(')#{$args}unquote(')')
    }
}

.bannerStyle01 {
    @include background( linear-gradient(to right,#e14504,#ff9016) ); 
    background-color: mix(#e14504,#ff9016); 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/*.bannerStyle02 {
    @include background( radial-gradient(to right,#e14504,#ff9016) ); 
    background-color: mix(#e14504,#ff9016); 
    border: 1px solid black;
}*/
```

When I try to compile with Web Essentials in VS2013, I get a message "Function parselinear finished without @return".

I've installed Scout and used that to fill the code with debug to try and trace why the function might be finishing without a @return statement, but I am unable to.

I know the message should be pretty clear, even pointing to the correct function that has the issue, and if I substitute the function for a namesake with a simple `@return "bob"`, then there are no issues.  Trouble is 2 days of investigation have not explained why I am still getting this message, despite all my debugging seeming to show that there is no capability for the function to finish without passing a returned value.

Any help taking a fresh look at this would be greatly appreciated - hopefully the fact I've isolated it into a block that can be used to create a simple scss file will help someone else try to run it on their command line/IDE.

Many thanks,

Alan

Comment: Really?  It takes *all* of this code to reproduce the error?

Comment: I saw this question already and believe me I assumed my problem was the same. Trouble is as I said in my original description I cannot find a case in my code where the function finished without a return.  I'm well aware that not all of this coffee is needed to produce the error, I simply wanted to provide a fully working block of code that could be dropped into an IDE for testing, without running the risk of inadvertently removing something crucial.

Comment: It is **your job** to find the smallest amount of code that can still reproduce the error.  Dumping this much code onto the community who graciously does this *for free* is a sign of disrespect.  The fact that you can't find the problem because you're unwilling to start removing things until the problem goes away comes at no surprise.

Comment: While I appreciate the lesson in etiquette cimmanon, and believe me I meant no disrespect to the venerable and noble StackOverflow membership, I merely decided to put the full code on there as I've explained twice before to make it easier to drop it into a test case and perhaps reproduce the issue with a fresh pair of eyes.  SCSS is new to me and while I appreciate that people are doing this out of the goodness of their hearts (and I've never suggested or assumed otherwise) I figured the way I included the code might make it easier to reproduce, it certainly wasn't out of laziness as you imply